# How is $1+5+9+...+[4(k+1)-3]=[1+5+9+...+(4k-3)]+4(k+1)-3$?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation

I couldn't solve a proof by induction and looking at the result (at the proof) on the book, they used this equivalence: 
 $1+5+9+...+[4(k+1)-3]=[1+5+9+...+(4k-3)]+4(k+1)-3$
How are these equal? The part $1+5+9+...$ is the same on both, so we should have $[4(k+1)-3]=(4k-3)+4(k+1)-3$ but how is this true?

$[4(k+1)-3]=4k+4-3=4k+1$

while

$(4k-3)+4(k+1)-3=4k-3+4k+4=8k+1$

this not the same, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: If the last term is $4(k+1)-3$, then the term immediately before that is $4k-3$, though it is part of the "...." in the left hand side. It is just like saying $1+2+3+...+100=1+2+3+...+99+100$, simply fleshing out some of the unwritten terms.

Answer (score 1):

The $(k-1)th$ term of LHS is:

$$4(k-1+1)-3=4k-3$$

So LHS can be written as:

$$[1+5+9+ \cdot \cdot\cdot +4k-3]+4(k+1)-3$$

Answer (score 0):

The same way

$$1+2+3+\cdots + 100 = 1+2+3+\cdots +99+100$$